# How to change the default analyzer for dynamic fields

Tags: ravendb

RavenDB uses the `LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer` by default and switches (if I'm not mistaken) to the  `StandardAnalyzer` if you set a field to `FieldIndexing.Analyzed`.

RavenDB also defaults to the `LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer` for dynamic fields.
I would like to change this. I want RavenDB to use the `StandardAnalyzer` for **ALL** my dynamic fields.

How can I do that?
Do I ***have*** to use a plugin and implement `AbstractAnalyzerGenerator`?
I would prefer not to since this will make deployment a lot more complicated for something as simple as changing the default analyzer.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem with the next code.

```
public class Product_ByFields : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Product>
    {
        public Product_ByFields()
        {
            Map = products => from product in products
                              select new
                              {
                                     _ = product.FieldValues.Select(f => CreateField(f.Key, f.Value.SearchTerms, false, true))
                              };

            this.Analyze("__all_fields", "Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
 _= CreateField("Foo", "bar", stored: false, analyzed: true);
```

Comment: Can you explain what's going on here?

Comment: I've tried this, but it was still using the LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer. (or at least when I inspected the Lucene index with Luke, the fieldvalues were not tokenized)